# Gtk Popover Menu is not using the default padding

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I created a `GtkPopoverMenu` and added some text buttons to it, but I can't get it to follow the same padding as other popovers, like the one in Nautilus.

The default style classes are being applied, and `GtkInspector` shows the same padding values as the popover in Nautilus, but, visually, the padding isn't there.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
pbox = Gtk.Box(orientation = Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
popover.add(pbox)

one = Gtk.ModelButton.new()
one.set_label("Button One")
pbox.pack_start(one, False, False, 0)

two = Gtk.ModelButton.new()
two.set_label("Button Two")
pbox.pack_start(two, False, False, 0)

three = Gtk.ModelButton.new()
three.set_label("Button Three")
pbox.pack_start(three, False, False, 0)
```

And how it looks vs how the one in Nautilus looks: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNwiE.png)

And the full code: [Code](http://pastebin.com/6wLQXY7A)

Am I missing something here?

Comment: @andlabs There's a link to an image in the question...

Comment: Nautilus also uses margins. You should try for example `one.set_property('margin', 10)`

Comment: @elya5 Thank you! This did the trick. Could you convert your comment into a answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nautilus uses a combination of margin and padding for its Popover.

I hope the screenshot demonstrates it. The first is the Popover as it is with your code. The second one has a margin but as you can see, the selection directly touches the text. Therefore the third Popover has margin and padding.

[image: screenshot of three different popovers]

The margin can be set with `widget.set_property('margin', 10)` and the padding with a css file.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much ;)